# is it good to make recyclerview adapter singleton?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i have a situation where i have to access my **Recyclerview adapter** from other     class instead the the class  where i create an object of adapter.
     So is it good to make it singleton object. please give solution.

Comment: You should include code so someone can tell you the correct way to implement your problem

Comment: Why do you need to access the adapter from another class?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede for notifyDatasetChanged() when data is updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, views and adapters should never be singletons because they're tied to an instance of the Activity.

Comment: then how can i access myadapter from other class not from the mainactivity

Comment: you need not write the adapter as an innerclass, extract it to a separate class file, then reuse the adapter in another activity and pass the same data values and you will be fine.

Comment: @redblood You can create a `getter` method which can `return` the `object` of your adapter `class`.